# How to factorize (decompose) the sum of matrix powers and its transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, power-series, matrix-decomposition, transpose

Suppose I have a matrix $M$, such that:

$$M = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c^{k}(A^{k})^{\top}DA^{k} = D + cA^{\top}DA + c^{2}A^{2\top}DA^{2} + \cdots,$$
where $c \in [0,1]$ is a scalar, D is a diagonal matrix with $(1-c)<D_{ii}<1$,
$A$ is a column stochastic matrix (sum of elements of each column is 1).
(This guarantee that this series would converge).

How can I get a facorization(decomposition) of M by $A$, such that:

$$M = R^{\top}R.$$

where $R$ is some matrix. We know that such a decomposition must exist, since $M$ is symmetric.

The problem is that I want this decomposition is expressed by $A$, i.e., $R = f(A)$, $f$ is some function work on $A$.

How can I get this decomposition (factorization) of $M$?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that when $A=[1]$ (scalar) or identity matrix, it won't converge. My hunch is that this won't converge with the assumptions you have. For instance, consider that $A$ is symmetric (doubly stochastic), then you can use SVD and the fact that largest eigenvalue is 1 to prove this series won't converge. However, I am not able to do it for the the non-symmetric case. Again, my guess is that you need the spectral radius (largest absolute eigenvalue) to be strictly less than 1 for this series to converge. Since your matrix is guaranteed to have a eigenvalue of 1, this may not happen.

Comment: @dineshdileep thanks, I have re-formulated the series for $M$, it would converge. Thanks for pointing out this issue.

Comment: now it looks more arbitrary :). Can you explain the motivation behind this?

Comment: @dineshdileep yes, in my problem formulation, $M$ is the solution of the first equation. But I want to decompose $M=R^{\top}R$ to make elements of $M$ are inner products. I just want know, whether is it possible to decompose $M$ using the information of $c,A,D$. Thanks.